# Fluids passing through effectors Mantaflow Blender 2.82

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

In one of my classes in college I was asked to animate a pipe with running water. I looked at many Youtube tutorials on fluid simulations and managed to make a simple one. However, when I try to make water go through a pipe, the fluid goes right through it. I've tried many things to correct it and so far nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: check this tutorial to check if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O0QcLpAxV4

Comment: Make the walls a little thicker, or increase the resolution of the bake. Additionally, if you are using the 2.83 beta, you will need to go to the pipe, and check "Use Effector". With this little info, unfortunately, it is hard to tell what happened and I recommend uploading your .blend.